# Preventing Form From Closing after invalid data asserted

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling, msgbox

I have a FormClosing Event Handler that upon action Shows a MessageBox with Two Buttons Yes Or No.
So if the user Clicks yes then it Checks values using a For loop and upon finding a invalid value How it SHOULD STAY ON THIS SAME FORM WITHOUT OPENING NEW ONE WITH ALL VALUSE RETAINED.

How can I accomplish this.

Simplified Code is as Shown:
(The class code resides in EditDataForm.vb That is Used by MainForm.vb Clas Code)

```
''' Closing Event that fired upon user closing the Form
Private Sub EditDataForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    If MessageBox.Show(Me, "Do you want to save your changes?", "Unsaved Changes!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        ButtonSave_Click(Me, e)
    Else
        Exit Sub    'Exit this Sub

    End If
End Sub




'''  Button Save Click Event 
  Private Sub ButtonSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click

Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim CheckDouble As Double

'' Leave the oth and 1th row
For rowIndex = 2 To masterDataGridView.RowCount - 1

    If TypeOf(masterDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Val").Value) is String Then

        Double.TryParse(masterDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Val").Value, CheckDouble)
        If(CheckDouble <= 0) Then
            MsgBox("Decimal Number Expect in place of:" & masterDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("Val").Value & "at Row Number:" & rowIndex + 1, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "FAILURE")

            '''''''' HOW CAN I STAY ON THIS SAME FORM
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If


Next

''Other Save Methods etc...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FormClosing eventhandler, set the `Cancel` property of the `FormClosingEventArgs` parameter to true.

It will prevent the form from closing:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

In order to integrate this in your application, I would create a method which validates your user-input.
This method should return something (a boolean for instance) which you can use to determine whether or not the data on your form is valid.

Use this method in the formclosing eventhandler, and verify there if the form should be closed or not:

```
Private Sub EditDataForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    If IsFormDataValid() = False Then

       e.Cancel = true
       Exit Sub 
    End if

    SaveData()
End Sub

Private Function IsFormDataValid() As Boolean

    ' Verify input, return true if data is valid; otherwise false.
End Function
```

Comment: After Adding e.Cancel = True As You Suggested. Like: 
ButtonSave_Click(Me, e)
e.Cancel = True
It does the same as expected. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have mixed C# and VB.NET syntax :). Semicolons aren't used in VB.NET and the comparison operator is `=`.